# Изменить содержание iframe

Tags: php, iframe

Чтобы получить контроль над содержанием подключенного к странице iframe был создан файл redirect.php с кодом:

```
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : false; // здесь нам надо получить сам адрес вставки
if (!$url) die(); // если его нет - ничего не делаем
$url = urldecode($url); // расдекодим все его вопросики и апресанды после передачи
$content = file_get_contents($url); // вся магия - получаем содержимое айфрейма

echo $content; // выводим измененное содержимое
```

Подключение iframe на веб-странице:

```
<iframe src="/redirect.php?url=http://site.ru/"></iframe>
```

Поиск строки в содержании айфрейме не срабатывает.

Как в айфрейме удалить ссылку на fonts.googleapis.com и JavaScript в head?

Такой способ не работает:

```
// поиск строки в содержании айфрейме
$pattern = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,700">';

// замена строки в айфрейме (в нашем случае пусто, т.е. удаляем)
$replacement = '';

// собираем в кучу
$content = str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще то iframe был создан специально, чтобы подгружать страницу без изменений и данный тег вам не подойдет для этой цели.
"Фреймы часто использовались для навигации по веб-сайту. При этом навигационная страница располагается в одном окне, а страницы с текстом — в другом" - Wiki.
Сейчас их не используют поскольку для поисковых роботов они не годятся. Если вы хотите показать страницу c другого ресурса с небольшими изменениями вам необходимо вывести страницу  в переменную, в этой переменной найти необходимый текст с помощью библеотеки DOM php - похожа на jqwery, либо с помощью регулярных выражений, а затем отдать пользователю.
Самый простой пример

```
$site=file_get_contents('https://ya.ru');
```